# C# WPF datagrid find and delete row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, find

Help me. i have `textbox` for find and `datagrid` for find . I want to search in the first column the rows with data similar to the data imported from the `textbox` and delete it. How do I do?

Thank for help. lucky new month

My code i try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
            TextBlock cellValue = datagrid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(datagrid.Items[0]) as TextBlock;
            string cellValue2 = cellValue.Text;
            if (cellValue2 == textbox.text) // check the search_string is present in the row of ColumnName
            {
                datagrid.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could/should delete the bound data  row in ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
for (int i = datagrid.Items.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var cellValue = datagrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(datagrid.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
    string cellValue2 = cellValue.Text;
    if (cellValue2 == textbox.Text) // check the search_string is present in the row of ColumnName
    {
        //For the case you set an ItemsSource:
        (datagrid.ItemsSource as IList)?.Remove(datagrid.Items[i]);
        //For the case you add Items directly:
        try
        {
            datagrid.Items.Remove(datagrid.Items[i]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
datagrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Don't forget to refresh the grid: `datagrid.Items.Refresh()`

Comment: 211/5000
I have tried this code. But it cannot work. There are 2 problems in this code. (datagrid.ItemsSource as IList) ?. Remove (_dgTest.Items [i]); 1 / IList)? and 2 / _dgTest can you help me. thank you very much.

Comment: `_dgTest` is just a typo use `datagrid` instead.

Comment: What is the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`?

Comment: (datagrid.ItemsSource as IList)? .....I still do not understand it. Can you describe it?

Comment: Does it work for you? Also you haven't answered my previous comment: _What is the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`_.

Comment: sorry, i don't know ItemsSource. my code:public class Customer

   ` public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
    
 }
 
 mybook memdrad = new mybook();
 memdrad.datagridFirstName = "smith";
 memdrad.datagridLastName = "jonh";
 memdrad.datagridAddress = "road9";
 datagrid.Items.Add(memdrad);`

Comment: It can help: [WPF overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/introduction-to-wpf)

Comment: Oh.yes. i try //For the case you add Items directly it work. but it remove one row. If I have more than 2 rows with a result textbox value it will only delete 1 row. I want it to delete all rows that have the same result with textbox value. how can i do. thank for help.

Comment: I try add: i = 0; after datagrid.Items.Remove(datagrid.Items[i]); let it repeat the event. but it still leaves 1 row.

Comment: I have modified the code. It's because of `GetCellContent`, it returns alwayse the first occurence. So start from the end and it will work.

Comment: i try your code. It worked. but if repeated several times it will error:"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

cellValue was null. "and I try to fix it using: if (cellValue! = null) it works and does not error  " System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

cellValue was null." but after several deletions it will continue to delete missing rows.